Geo Node Bounding Box UVs similar to Correct Face Attributes
I would like a bounding box created by geometry nodes to function as a boolean, and to use the texture of the bounding box for the texture of the hole.
Normally, the texture changes when the main object is scaled.

However, when the object has certain dimensions the object scales similar to "Correct Face Attributes".

The uv behavior here makes the bounding box real convenient as a boolean!

The uv behavior is also consistent with various dimensions.

However, the uvs always change sizes once a certain width is reached. I'm wondering if any uv guru can figure out a way to keep the "correct face attributes" behavior regardless of the width of the object?
